# Scrapy, Crawl papers from ICML

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to crawl papers from ICML proceedings with `Scrapy`, and my code is

`items.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

import scrapy

from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class PapercrawlerItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    title = Field()
    pdf = Field()
    sup = Field()
```

`spider.py`

```
from scrapy import Spider

from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from PaperCrawler.items import PapercrawlerItem


class PaperCrawler(Spider):
    name = "PaperCrawler"
    allowed_domains = ["proceedings.mlr.press"]
    start_urls = ["http://proceedings.mlr.press/v97/", ]

    def parse(self, response):
        papers = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]')

        titles = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/p[1]')
        pdfs = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/p[3]/a[2]')
        sups = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/p[3]/a[3]')

        for title, pdf, sup in zip(titles, pdfs, sups):
            item = PapercrawlerItem()
            item['title'] = title.xpath('text()').extract()[0]
            item['pdf'] = pdf.xpath('@href').extract()[0]
            item['sup'] = sup.xpath('@href').extract()[0]
            yield item
```

However, it only returned contents of the first paper. I want to crawl all the papers in the link. How can I fix it?

```
[
{"title": "AReS and MaRS Adversarial and MMD-Minimizing Regression for SDEs", "pdf": "http://proceedings.mlr.press/v97/abbati19a/abbati19a.pdf", "sup": "http://proceedings.mlr.press/v97/abbati19a/abbati19a-supp.pdf"}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in *div/div[2]*. Crawler doesn't iterate since you have specified a specific div number. Instead you can specify a selector for the div, eg. *div[@class="paper"]* in this case and then the code works fine.

Here is the corrected code:

```
class PaperCrawler(Spider):
    name = "PaperCrawler"
    allowed_domains = ["proceedings.mlr.press"]
    start_urls = ["http://proceedings.mlr.press/v97/", ]

    def parse(self, response):
        papers = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[@class="paper"]')

        titles = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[@class="paper"]/p[1]')
        pdfs = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[@class="paper"]/p[3]/a[2]')
        sups = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[@class="paper"]/p[3]/a[3]')

        for title, pdf, sup in zip(titles, pdfs, sups):
            item = PapercrawlerItem()
            item['title'] = title.xpath('text()').extract()[0]
            item['pdf'] = pdf.xpath('@href').extract()[0]
            item['sup'] = sup.xpath('@href').extract()[0]
            yield item
```

By iterating the papers and check the length of `sup` can fix it

```
class PaperCrawler(Spider):
    name = "PaperCrawler"
    allowed_domains = ["proceedings.mlr.press"]
    start_urls = ["http://proceedings.mlr.press/v97/", ]

    def parse(self, response):
        papers = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[@class="paper"]')

        for paper in papers:
            item = PapercrawlerItem()
            item['title'] = paper.xpath('p[1]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['pdf'] = paper.xpath('p[3]/a[2]/@href').extract()[0]
            _sup_data = paper.xpath('p[3]/a[3]/@href').extract()
            item['sup'] = '' if len(_sup_data) == 0 else (_sup_data[0] if 'github' not in _sup_data[0] else '')
            yield item
```

Comment: Thank you, but I found it only returns data with non-empty `sups` (papers with Supplementary PDF). How can I return all the data on the page?